# Getting `Java Heap` memory issue when we ran with log level as 'DEBUG' in logback-test.xml

Tags: karate

Getting `Java Heap` memory issue when we ran features with log level as 'DEBUG' in logback-test.xml.

We've ran around 400 feature. could you please help on this issue.

its maven project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to version 0.9.0 please.

Comment: issue got  resolved after upgrading version. thank you so much @Peter.